# Sanitizing both HTML and SQL at once?

Tags: php, sql, html

Right now I am using `htmlspecialchars(mysql_escape_string($value))`, but is there a way to sanitize it with one statement rather than a nested statement?

Comment: No, there is no magical escape function, you need to prepare your data for the medium you are outputting to.

Comment: [mysql_ functions are deprecated](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). If possible use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: On a side note: sql escaping should come after html escaping, otherwise you may still be at risk of sql injection, corrupted data, or just broken queries. Seems unlikely, but the order should be fixed regardless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mysql_real_escape_string` has actually fallen out of favor lately.

It is now preferred to use `PDO` or `mysqli`. They both come with PHP by default. They use something called `parameterized queries` to access the database, rather than having you write the SQL command yourself. This means that you don't need to worry about escaping anymore, since the query and the variables are passed into the function separately.

You can learn more about PDO here:
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/

On a related note, it is conventional to store user-supplied input into the database "as it was written", rather than using `htmlspecialchars`. You should then use `htmlspecialchars` to escape the data wherever the it appears on the site. This is a convention recommended by [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/).

This is because you need to escape different things depending on context. This string:

```
' <script src="http://example.org/malice.js"></script> ]}\\\\--
```

...will need to be treated differently if it is used as a parameter in `JSON` (the quotes and backslashes and `]` and `}` need to be escaped), `HTML` (the quotes and `<`s need to be escaped), or written as a `URL` (almost everything needs to be escaped). If you need to spend time instructing your JavaScript to un-encode the HTML, then your code is going to be confusing quickly.

This approach also makes fixing bugs simpler: if your site has a bug where content isn't escaped properly on a single page, then you can update the page and everything is fixed. If your site has a bug where the data is getting stored in the database incorrectly, then you need to fix everything in the database (which will take much longer and harm more users).

Answer (score 2):

Well there's no one function that handles both of them.
You can use prepared statements and html puffier class, maybe then the "look and feel" will be little bit better :)